# Append multiple List with computation expression

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I have a function that generates some elements and returns them in a List. The function take a parameter to filter returned elements. The function looks like this:

```
let create x = [1..1000] |> List.filter (fun c -> (c % x) = 0)
```

Now I would like to call this function with multiple criteria and append all results into a single List.

At first I was thinking doing this:

```
let result = (create 100) 
            |> List.append (create 300) 
            |> List.append (create 500) 
            |> List.append (create 3)
printf "%A" result
```

But I didn't find this solution elegant and repetitive with the `List.append` expression.

I had tried a second solution:

```
let result = [100; 300; 500; 3] |> List.map (fun c -> create c) 
                                |> List.reduce (fun acc c -> acc |> List.append c)
printf "%A" result
```

This solution is more concise but there is something that I don't like about it. I found it less clear and more difficult to guess what we tried to achieve.

So, I was looking for a third solution and tried to implement a new solution with computation expression:

```
type AppendBuilder() =
    member this.Bind (x, f) = f x |> List.append x
    member this.Return x = x
```

And then use it like that:

```
let append = new AppendBuilder()
let result = append {
    let! a = create 100
    let! b = create 300
    let! c = create 500
    let! d = create 3

    return []
}
printf "%A" result
```

This last solution works and I prefer it. I found it more clear, easier to understand what we are doing and without the repetetive List.append expression. But there is still something wrong. I don't like the `return []` part, this seems un-natural and unclear. But this trick is necessary to make it work.

The third solution is my favorite but I'm not sure this is the right way to solve my problem. It solves the problem, I get the correct result but I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Can I keep the third solution without causing confusion about my intention? Does the solution is clear enough to keep it as is? I'm looking for a solution that is more focused on the action (here calling `create x`) without repetitive expression that parasite the code (here calling `List.append`).

Comment: what about `[100;300;500;3] |> List.collect create`

Comment: I prefer @JohnPalmer 's solution over all of the posted answers. It makes best use of the library functions, and - in contrast to all posted solutions - allows for the arguments (`[100;300;500;3]`) to come from a previous computation step.

Comment: Yes, better to represent your computation as a transformation of data as a starting point and then move away from that if other requirements (e.g. performance) demand it.

Comment: Of interest: [Lambda Lifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_lifting) Noted not for this particular question, but for the concept of refactoring functional code in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let result = 
    [
        yield! [ 100 .. 100 .. 1001]
        yield! [ 300 .. 300 .. 1001]
        yield! [ 500 .. 500 .. 1001]
        yield! [ 3 .. 3 .. 1001]
    ]
```

Of note: Having worked with Python list I do find them more friendly because you can use the value `1000` instead of the value `1001` for F#.

If your `create` function is always a `step function` then using the built-in ability of List makes more sense. If you plan to use a `create` function that cannot make use of the built-in capabilities of List then the comment by [John Palmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124259/john-palmer) makes more sense.

```
let result = 
    [100;300;500;3] 
    |> List.collect create
```

A variation suggest in the comment by [Anton Schwaighofer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5979993/anton-schwaighofer) would be to allow the values for the `create` function to come in as a parameter.

```
let makeList parms =
    parms
    |> List.collect create
```

and then be used as

```
let result = makeList [100;300;500;3]
```

or even [pointfree](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree)

```
let makeList = List.collect create
```

Answer (score 7):

Since this was requested as an answer:

The easiest way is to use `List.collect` which esentially does the map and combining the lists in one step.

The solution in this case looks like

```
[100;300;500;3] |> List.collect create
```

Answer (score 2):

If the 3rd one is your favourite version then you might want to use list comprehension:

```
let result = 
    [ yield! create 100
      yield! create 300
      yield! create 500
      yield! create 3 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can benefit from laziness of `seq` computation:

```
seq {
    yield! create 100
    yield! create 300
    yield! create 500
    yield! create 3
} |> List.ofSeq
```

and then compute the list using `List.ofSeq`